# Media disconnected when connecting two computers using ethernet cable

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have two computers connected with an RJ45 Ethernet cable, one of the computers recognises it  but the other computer doesn't.

For the computer that doesn't recognise the connection, typing `ipconfig` at the command prompt displays "Media disconnected" for the Ethernet connection. 
Both computers recognise the Ethernet cable in device manager.

Do both computers need to be on the same subnet? What else needs to be setup?

Comment: You do use a **crossed** cable, right?

Comment: @slhck +1 you keep getting here first now!!!

Comment: @aspdotnetuser Can you confirm?